# How can I write a script to kill process that runs for a few hours?

Tags: unix, shell

I run python script from cron every hour on CentOS 5 and see some processes keep running for a few hours 
I would like to run a script every few hours to kill those processes. 
How can I write the script that terminate the process?

Answer (score 2):

No need to build a watcher script, check the *timeout* command.

```
timeout 2h your_python_script
```

This command will kill *your_python_script* if it's still running after 2 hours.